# How to show outputs of python code in a custom window?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

Why does this code show nothing? What is wrong here?

```
import tkinter
import tkinter.font as tkFont
window=tkinter.Tk()
window.geometry("720x720")
fontStyle = tkFont.Font(family="Verdana", size=50)
tkinter.Label(window, text = "HELLO", font=fontStyle).pack()
tkinter.Label(window, text = "HELLO", font=fontStyle).pack()
from time import sleep
for i in range(0,10):
    tkinter.Label(window, text = i, font=fontStyle).pack()
    sleep(3)
```

I was trying to show all the outputs of the python code on a GUI window rather than the idle.

Comment: Use `.after()` to replace the for loop and add `window.mainloop()` at the end of the script.

Comment: Read [`sleep()` block the `.mainloop`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58377804/7414759) and [Tkinter understanding mainloop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29158220/tkinter-understanding-mainloop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't starting the `tkinter` main loop.

Add

```
window.mainloop()
```

at the end (but do remember that tkinter then has control over your program).

Comment: At which line should i add that?

Comment: It also shows the error AttributeError: module 'tkinter' has no attribute 'Application'

Comment: Oops, my bad. Meant `window.mainloop()`. At the very end.