# Enable multithreading/processes in tkinter GUI

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, python-multiprocessing

My tkinter application has a function which has a time.sleep() function in it so anytime I run the function that has the time.sleep() function, the whole application freezes until seconds specified in the time.sleep() function has elapsed. This can be a very bad User experience and I need to fix this.

The function that has the time.sleep() function is a call back function from a button so I tried doing something like this:

```
from tkinter import *
import threading
root = Tk()

schedule_msg_btn = Button(root, text="Schedule Msg", command=lambda : threading.Thread(target=schedule_msg_func).start())
root.mainloop()
```

It seems to be doing absolutely nothing.

Comment: The fix is not to use threading but to use `after()` method. There are hundreds of post about `sleep` and `after` in tkinter. For the most part any one of them can fix your problem.

Comment: Piggybacking on @Mike-SMT - [here's a link](https://www.pythontutorial.net/tkinter/tkinter-after/) to some documentation on the `after` method

Comment: Here is a post where I give an an example with after and funny enough an example with threading. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58376456/python-tkinter-sleep-after-not-working-as-expected/58377804#58377804

Comment: Okay, thanks alot.  But what about a situation where the function runs a  a for loop and the application still freezes how do I fix that

Comment: @Coder that sounds like a really heavy for loop. Depending on the implementation you can use threading to manage something that heavy but I would avoid threading if I were you as tkinter is not thread safe and as a beginner its best to avoid threading all together until you can fully understand what its doing and the correct way to use it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Tkinter sleep/after not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58376456/python-tkinter-sleep-after-not-working-as-expected)

Comment: Okay I've looked through the contents of the link and I must say they look promising ... Thanks for your help I'll try using after for the call back function and threading for the for loop ..

Comment: @Mike-SMT wow it worked...  I mean the after widget ... Thanks

Comment: @coder the `after()` method was specifically designed to manage the timing issues to avoid the pitfalls of `sleep()` in a single threaded application like tkinters mainloop. Glad you got it working :)

Comment: @Mike-SMT thanks a lot. I was able to integrate the threading concept into most functions of my app and I have noticed that it is a lot smoother. And it sure will improve user experience. I just wonder how I have never really used threading in my other apps.... hehe